# CMake Error: Command add_definitions() is not scriptable

Tags: cmake

Has anyone ever come across this error? If so how do I fix it or what is an equivalent approach.

I am running Ubuntu and the code creates a list of compiler defines and then I am just looping through the list and adding each define.

```
set(COMPILER_DEF_LIST)
list(APPEND COMPILER_DEF_LIST_COMMON
 NUMBER_FAMILY_RESERVED_FIXED_OIDS=5
 CHILD_LIST_ELEMENTS_PER_BLOCK=10
 ...

FOREACH(compilerDefine ${COMPILER_DEF_LIST_COMMON})
add_definitions(-D${compilerDefine})
ENDFOREACH(compilerDefine)
```

Comment: Please, describe the situation when you get this error.

Comment: Updated the post above

Comment: Did you tried some debugging? E.g., which `foreach` iteration cause the error, what is value of `compilerDefine` at that iteration?

Comment: Please add the code context calling this CMake script also.

Answer (score 9):

This error message is specific to CMake being run in "script mode" with [`cmake -P ...`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake.1.html).

Mainly all commands handling targets and target settings/options/properties are not "scriptable" (not usable when running CMake in "script mode").

See also [CMake/Language Syntax: cmake -P](https://cmake.org/Wiki/CMake/Language_Syntax#cmake_-P):

> ... except that all commands related to Makefile generation or the CMake cache will fail

Comment: (For now redirection notice is working but to be on a safer side) Seems like the page linked moved to https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/community/-/wikis/doc/cmake/Language-Syntax.